# How can I create a new class and create a new variable of its type?

Tags: java, class, variables, debugging, drjava

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class XFrame extends JFrame {

}
```

I saved with name XFrame and compiled it, no bug. But when I want to create a new variable of type XFrame in the interaction pane:

```
new XFrame()
```

It showed "Static Error : Undefined class 'XFrame' "

Comment: could be your XFrame class in defferent package from package in which you want create new vaiable?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create an object of type XFrame you need to declare a variable that refers to XFrame. For example you could try

```
XFrame myFrame = new XFrame();
```

**EDIT**

You need to create the object in the main method

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class XFrame extends JFrame {

}

public static void main(String [ ] args)
{
      XFrame myFrame = new XFrame();
}
```

Here's a link for more info about the main method 
https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method

Comment: same error, I start to think it's my computer's problem, I did it 100% same as what my professor did.

Comment: You need to put your code in a main method like this:  `public static void main(String[] args) {

}`